# Group by a result of Case Substring SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having this query below and am unable to get the result of the full quantity when I use group by

```
SELECT CASE SUBSTRING(Data_Code, 3,1) 
         WHEN '1' THEN 'SS' 
         ELSE 'FW' 
       END + SUBSTRING(Data_Code, 1,2) [MyNewColumn]
SUM(QUANTITY) 
FROM [MyTable]
GROUP BY Data_Code
```

below is the sample of the table

```
|DataCode|Quantity|
|22263738| 10     |
|22251616| 15     |
```

am expecting to have a result of 25

Looking forwards to your kind help

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a sub-query

```
SELECT
    MyNewColumn
    , SUM(QUANTITY) 
FROM (
    SELECT
        QUANTITY
        , CASE SUBSTRING(Data_Code, 3,1) 
        WHEN '1' THEN 'SS' 
        ELSE 'FW'
        END + SUBSTRING(Data_Code, 1,2) MyNewColumn
    FROM MyTable
) X
GROUP BY MyNewColumn;
```

Comment: Hi Dale K, appreciated your kind response; is the X here referring to an alias for the MyTable?

Comment: Yes... you have to alias all derived tables.

Comment: you've been super useful, thx again